# Cordova platform add creates platforms folder in wrong path

Tags: android, cordova, ant, cordova-3

I have a simple project with some files in a www/ folder.
In the same folder i create my cordova project with the call

```
cordova create cordova com.test.app Testapp --copy-from=www/
```

This creates my cordova folder with the content from www/ inside the cordova/www/ folder which is fine so far.

Now if i call

```
cordova platform add android
```

it fails looking for plugins/android.json in my root folder not inside cordova/.
After that i figured out, that this command created the platforms/android folder inside my root folder instead of the cordova/ folder.

So its pointing to the parent folder even if im inside cordova/ calling the platform add command. Whats going wrong here? I thought cordova always works relative to the current path. But now it seems its getting up to the parent folder adding platforms there and looking for the plugins folder. How can i fix that?

I'm using Cordova 3.5.0 and have set up android-sdk with java 1.7.0_65 and ant in PATH and JAVA_HOME.

I can easily create the demo HelloWold project and add platforms, but not in my web project.

I would like to automate it by calling a shell script, but since cordova points to the wrong folder, it doesn't work.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: maybe you forgot cd cordova? You have to be in the project to run commands other than create. (you may have 50 projects in the folder you are when you run create and the cli can't know which to pick)

Comment: i know that. iam inside the newly created cordova folder but still it creates the platforms out one level up, so its the cordova command is still pointing to the level where my origin www/ is located.

Comment: ok it looks like its because of the ---copy-from parameter i add to the cordova create command. this parameter allows me to copy an existing www source instead of getting the HelloWorld one created. but then i need to copy manually which is annoying. This MUST BE a bug. So cordova points to the level where it got the www/ source with the --copy-from parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you don't understand here is that when you run the command

`cordova create cordova com.test.app Testapp --copy-from=www`

the cli will use your www folder to create a new project in the newly created folder named "cordova".
So you have to type `cd cordova` before you can run any cli command.

I have successfully ran the following commands:

```
cordova create cordova com.test.app Testapp --copy-from=www
cd cordova
cordova platform add android
```

And I would also suggest you use an other name instead of cordova as parameter of the create command :

```
cordova create testapp com.test.app Testapp --copy-from=www
```